# Is simple authentication safe if over HTTPS?

Tags: authentication, php

**Background**
For my app I need to know if users have entered the correct email password combo. Pretty common stuff. I'm using HTTPS, and salting and hashing the passwords.

**Question**
Now, what I am wondering is if I should literally respond from my server with JSON that says `successfulLogin:true`/`successfulLogin:false`?

**My thoughts**
To me that seems fair, but I am not certain if this would be easy for someone to fake and send. Something else I am doing is that I'm sending a key with the POST so that the PHP script will only run if its key and that key match.

Comment: What would happen in your application if someone responds with a fake `{"successfulLogin:true"}`?

Comment: @Jedi So I guess this is what I'm wondering. Essentially it would let them log into any account they knew the email address for. As of now, this is strictly an iOS app. Is there a way someone actually could intercept my request to my web server (being that its https) and reply that? If not, any links to best practice?

Comment: State must be at the server not the mobile app. Set a session. Search for tutorials for something like *ios app + your_web_framework + session management*

Comment: Could you try to clarify the last sentence a bit? Is it a constant key that is the same for all clients? Or are you talking about a CSRF token? Or a session ID?

Comment: spoofing that simple response should not allow seeing other's emails, or you've got way bigger issues...

Comment: The best recommendation I could give you is to let a framework handle this for you. As an experienced developer and security-versed being I would not dare to roll my own auth system. If you are not an expert, you will create flaws, that will possibly end up being exploited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Authentication

The server must take care of the state (e.g. is the user logged in or not), not the client. While it is perfectly fine to send JSON with information about the state (e.g. yes, you are logged in) over HTTPS, it is the server that must remember if the particular user is logged in or not. The server can never trust the client.

The way you do this is to use a session variable on the server, i.e. a variable connected to this particular user, that keeps track on if she is logged in or not:

```
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
```

Then everytime the user requests information that should only be available for logged in users, you need to check that this session variable is indeed true. That way it does not matter if someone fiddled with your JSON response - unless they provided the right password the server will still not view them as logged in.

Read more about sessions in PHP [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

One more thing - if your client holds sensitive data that should not be made available to the userunless the server authanticates her then this is quite a different situation, and you would need to take further precautions. The same is true if the client performs actions on behalf of the user.

## Sending key in POST

> Something else I am doing is that I'm sending a key with the POST so that the PHP script will only run if its key and that key match.

Not sure what you are saying here. This could be completely superfluous, but I am not sure I understand it correctly.

## Rolling your own

Keep in mind that doing a complete authentication system is not easy. There are loads of pitfalls other than those covered in this post. Instead of rolling your own, I would suggest you check if there is some existing PHP framework that you can use.